# How much applicable is raspberry pi at industrial point of view?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, raspberry-pi

As a student I have to design a project for automation of greenhouse. I can use single board controller as Arduino or I can use Raspberry Pi as well. I understand difference that one is microcontroller based and another is CPU based board. If I talk in terms of industrial application what experience will give me a better skill from perspective of industry's demand.

Comment: there's going to be a larger existing demand for microcontrollers, the rest is opinion-based.

Comment: In an "industrial" setting you wouldn't use either one. You'd use some kind of big expensive controller box. Use the one that makes the most sense for your project and don't try to shoehorn your project into the wrong platform.

Comment: I fully agree with @Daniel. I developed network device on some networking chip for $10; it is great within such Raspberry and Adruino test-and-play environment, but when it comes to highly loaded networks and *handling network errors* this chip does the bad job *by design*.

Comment: @dandavis thanks so working on microcontroller based system will reflect that means

Comment: well, not ardunios, but you see micros in about everything these days...

Comment: @Daniel I understand that but if industry hires a fresher what sort of experience they expect that was my main concern

Comment: It depends completely on what industry you're talking about.

Comment: If it's out there, somebody uses it. Sharpen up your design skills by doing more designs -- not fretting over who is using what -- you're going to learn something no matter which one you use.

Comment: People want to see that you can take a pile of parts and turn it into something.

Comment: @daniel I am talking about automation industry

Answer (score 5):

No. In engineering point of view both Arduino and Raspberry PI's are bare minimum example boards. They do not feature the ruggedness required for an 24/7-365 industrial application.

You can add these features with extra boards. But you will still have a weak core you've build upon.
*This is not entirely valid for Arduino, since you can use only the software*

Go for an PLC instead. Look at CodeSys for suitable brands for example. (eg: wago)

I can link some greenhouse controllers I've found on Shodan.io, but that feels wrong. Please secure your automation!

**But**, I understand you're a student, and a PLC might not be available or within course context. In that case, I'd suggest you go for Raspberry PI.
Why?
- It has Ethernet by default.
- It runs linux. Which means it has no probleem running an [HMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_interface).
- It has USB, which means you can add any external interface for IO or communcations.
For examples, to use Wago CANopen Fieldbus Device. Or their Ethernet variant. Instead of using the weak unprotected GPIO's on the processor board.

Comment: Context is everything! I like how you covered both the Student and non-student one.

Answer (score 0):

On the microcontroller side, the arduino is only really useful to you as an atmel dev kit. Program the microcontroller using C. The only times the arduino software gets used by actual professionals is when they need to hammer out some quick thing for a prototype or testing system as a quick bandaid.

On the raspberry pi side, it's good for learning how to use linux. Learning how to use linux at a lower level, configuring the device tree, and interacting with other devices is a useful skill. There's lots of other small form factor linux computers such as the wandboard which get used in industrial applications, or you may find yourself developing your own system running a linux os. I've seen instances of people actually using raspberry pi's for monitoring or running test systems. They're quite versatile devices.

Answer (score 0):

I think your should consider using both a Raspberry Pi and an Arduino (I really recommend the Arduino Nano). 
The reason for both is that the R'Pi gives you a Linux base OS with lots of storage, ready Internet access, advanced peripherals such as High resolution display, Ethernet and Wi-Fi with readily available drivers. You can even get a power fail/BBU daughterboard if needed.

The Arduino allows you to develop your low level interfaces and present them as simple Serial or I2C slave connections to the R'Pi. Here you have cut down software, but easily developed in their GUI. You can program the Arduino directly from the R'PI over the USB interface....read [this](http://razzpisampler.oreilly.com/ch10.html).

What's not to love.....and both are good experience to have.

Comment: Beware you're not re-inventing simple IO boards.

Comment: @Jeroen3 Of course that is always true of any self developed board that might not be as reliable as commercial offerings. But for a student environment they are ideal teaching devices.